# How to tell javac which libraries to include

Tags: command-line, java, gnome-terminal

So I am trying to run a java file from Terminal. But the file is using the apache.commons.io lib, so a simple javac MyFile.java does not work here.

How do you include the libraries in Terminal?

Comment: You include the libraries needed in your java source and include the classpath using `-cp` on the terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need first to install `libcommons-io-java`:

```
sudo apt-get install libcommons-io-java
```

Then use the installed jar file with `javac` this way:

```
javac my_file.java -cp /usr/share/java/commons-io.jar
```

From the `javac` man pages:

> ```
>       -cp path or -classpath path
>          Specify where to find user class files, and (optionally)  annota‐
>          tion  processors  and source files. This class path overrides the
>          user class path in the CLASSPATH environment variable. If neither
>          CLASSPATH,  -cp  nor -classpath is specified, the user class path
>          consists of the current directory. See Setting the Class Path for
>          more details.
> ```